# How to align on center of the page a longtable inside a ThreePartTable?

Tags: align, longtable, threeparttable

I am trying to resize a ThreePartTable in the page but I always get an error. The code so far goes like this:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{threeparttablex}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{threeparttablex}
    \usepackage{lscape}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{ThreePartTable}
            \begin{TableNotes} 
        \small
        \item Notes: 
    \end{TableNotes}

        \begin{longtable}{lrrrrrrrr}

        \caption{Results}
        \label{results}

        \\ \toprule
        &   AAAAA   &   BBBBB   &   CCCCC   &   DDDDD   &   EEEEE   &   FFFFF & GGGGGGG & HHHHHHHHH 
    \\ \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{9}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous
    page}}\\
        \toprule
    &   AAAAA   &   BBBBB   &   CCCCC   &   DDDDD   &   EEEEE   &   FFFFF & GGGGGGG & HHHHHHHHH 
    \\ \midrule
        \endhead

        \midrule
        \multicolumn{9}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
        \midrule
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule

        \insertTableNotes         %% this added
        \endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{Panel A: aaaaa}         \\ 
        \hline


aa aaa  &   \textbf{1111**}&    \textbf{1111**}&    \textbf{1111**}&    \textbf{1115**} &   \textbf{1111**} &   \textbf{1111*}  &   \textbf{1111**} &   \textbf{1111**} \\
bbbbbb &    11111   &   \textbf{1111**} &   1111 &  \textbf{1111*}  &   1111 &  \textbf{11111**}    &   1111    &   \textbf{1111*}  \\


    \end{longtable}

    \end{ThreePartTable}

    \end{document}
```

If we run the code we observe that the table is aligned a bit more on the right, rather than in the center. How can I align the Table in the center of the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with your MWE your longtable is overflowing beyond not even the right margin but even the right side of page

Comment: I am not sure what MWE means. However, how could I place this table in the middle of the page?

Comment: MWE means [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) but here I was simply referring to your posted code (which is probably not all minimal). Even if placed in middle of the page it will overflow perhaps, are you sure it fits on the page?

Comment: Yes. Just compiled the code and it fits in one page, but is not centered.

Comment: Do you really need `longtable`, i.e. splitting across pages? Unfortunately LaTeX2e is a big mess of hundreds of packages with no strict document layout programming interface. Just to give an example, I tested that `ThreePartTable` is not compatible with list environments. As LaTeX2e uses at a lot of places list environments one could expect all "display" environments to have to be compatible with them, but alas this is not the case. Even at core LaTeX2e and standard classes which implements table of contents in a way incompatible with a surrounding list environment.